# Programming books in ePub format

Tags: php, jquery, python, epub

I purchased an iPad hoping to read books on it that've been aging on my desk for months, but it turned out that there're NO programming books available on iBookstore.

Are there any (Python, PHP, jQuery) books available in ePub format? Conversion from pdf to  epub is not an option because the formatting is lost in the process.

Thanks

Comment: Apple is going to keep losing popularity with developers if they don't remember we exist sooner or later

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can buy all O'Reilly books straight off their [website](http://oreilly.com/) in ePub and many other formats. Should work fine on the iPad (don't have one myself).

Comment: Thanks, I also just found out that the cheap o'Reilly books for iPhone can be used as ePub books on iPad: http://zef.me/3246/convert-cheap-oreilly-iphone-app-books-to-epub; but as I suspected, the code formatting sucks. snippets are realyl small, making them large also makes the rest of the book text too large. I thought we'd see books that'd have syntax colored code snippets, but this is the opposite. Hmm...

Answer (score 8):

I found two free and good ePub programming books so far

- [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP)](http://github.com/downloads/ieure/sicp/sicp.epub)
- [ProGIT](https://github.s3.amazonaws.com/media/progit.epub)

Answer (score 5):

[Manning](http://manning.com) has [some programming books](http://manning.com/catalog/mobile/) available in *epub* and *mobi* formats.

Answer (score 3):

Pragmatic Programmers (http://pragprog.com/) publish a variety of good to excellent programming books, all of which are available in ePub format from their website. You can purchase text, digital, or a mix (where digital is available in both epub and pdf format).

That said, I'm afraid little of their content is towards python, php, or jquery. It's mostly ruby, ruby on rails, iphone/mac, and general programming issues and techniques. Still, the content is excellent.

I would also repeat @Hagge's comment that OReilly has quite a bit available in ePub format, and they *do* cover the python, php, and (to a small extent) jquery topics. Dig around in the site at http://oreilly.com/ebooks/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be ePub format?

Here in Australia the iBookstore is basically completely bare, except for books out of copyright (The illiad, Bible etc) My understanding is that they are still negotiating with the publishers.

The guy at the Apple store said to me, oh thats no problem, download the free Kindle app and just buy your books from Amazon, they have a much better range anyway.

Would that work for you?

Comment: Yep, I like the fancy page turning in iBooks :P But seriously, iBooks is way better than Kindle app. I'm surprised there're NO programming books available in ePub format!

Comment: FWIW I totally agree with your assesment re iBooks v's Kindle....however iBooks with no content is just useless. Kindle/SomeOtherReader with content is better than nothing.